# Problem with table borders when loading a DOCX document using the PHPWord library

Tags: php, html, phpword

I am using a PHP library to read a DOCX document and convert it to HTML. The document contains two tables, but the first table doesn't have borders. The issue is that when the document is converted to HTML, the table is rendered with borders, and I don't understand why. I also tried converting it to PDF to see if the problem was with the HTML conversion, but the PDF file generated exhibits the same problem.

I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions to resolve this issue. Below is the code I am using, which is quite simple.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;

$phpWord = IOFactory::load('test.docx', 'Word2007');

$htmlWriter = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\HTML($phpWord);
$htmlWriter->save('test.html');
```